# How to show Percentage Sign in AchartEngine Pie Chart in Android

Tags: android, achartengine, pie-chart

How to show percentage sign in AchartEngine Pie chart?

I have googled and tried to achieve it with showing percentage by using `renderer.setChartTitle("All");`

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use that in the legend by having each series containing it in its title.

```
CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries("title");
```